# Twitter Oauth in windows phone 8 app

Tags: twitter, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I need to use Twitter Oauth to login my windows phone app,

What i need exactly is

1)when the user click twitter log in button from my app, i need to show the twitter llog in page in a browser,
2)when he enters his credentials and accept the app, then i should get the user information like, name, gender, bday, what ever i can take.

That,s it, then i can close the browser and make my app active.

I just need to make the user to log in via twitter.

I referred lot of examples, that are all quit confusing and doing all the stuffs in twiiter.

I tried [this example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/wp7-integrating-twitter-with-your-app/)

and got this error

```
'TweetSharp.TwitterService' does not contain a definition fError    2   'TweetSharp.TwitterService' does not contain a definition for 'GetAccessToken' and no extension method 'GetAccessToken' accepting a first argument of type 'TweetSharp.TwitterService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and i tried [enter link description here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Latest-Twitter-integration-a42e8bb6)

failed on that too.

Can anybody help me to do the authentication via twitter for my app.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Latest-Twitter-integration-a42e8bb6) and got success, I contacted the person who have posted that example and got help from him to solve the issues raised from this example.

Actually this Example works fine for twitter integration,

What you have to do is

1)Register your app in twitter, here the  [link for app registration](https://dev.twitter.com/),

log in and register your app.

2)Make sure you have given the Call Back URL(i forget to give that, and that makes me face lot of issues)

3)Note down the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret and Call back url(we need specify this 3 in our code)

4)Go to Settings, and set your app access to Read and Write

5)down load the above link and change the Consumer Key, Consumer Secret and Call back url as per your app, and then run the example, it will work fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to authenticate using Twitter and don't want to post anything, perhaps you can try Azure Mobile Service Authentication. You can find more information here: [mobile services authentication](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-users-wp8/)

Comment: Hi, am just including more options to log in into my app, I have already did log in via, google, facebook. And now i need to add twitter option too.